# как задать вопрос в личку

Tags: поддержка

Как задать вопрос конкретному человеку в личку здесь ?

Comment: такого функционала вроде тут нет

Comment: Ни  как... Максимум можешь обратиться написав коммент к вопросу или ответу, не забудь обратиться к `@NIK`, что-бы  человек к которому обращаешься получил уведомление...